# ClassCastException in FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button

got ClassCastException in android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton after updating com.android.support:design lib to 24.2.0. its working fine in lib version 24.1.1

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior.isBottomSheet(FloatingActionButton.java:597)
   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior.onDependentViewChanged(FloatingActionButton.java:589)
   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$Behavior.onDependentViewChanged(FloatingActionButton.java:528)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.offsetChildToAnchor(CoordinatorLayout.java:1564)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onChildViewsChanged(CoordinatorLayout.java:1233)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener.onPreDraw(CoordinatorLayout.java:1812)
   at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2000)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

Comment: Please don't just dump an error log here and expect us to know your code and debug it for you. Post your *relevant* code and add details to your question so we can assist you

Comment: May be you didn't update same version as 24.2.0 for your support library in gradle file....

Comment: @Andrew L just put android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton in my xml file. its working fine in lib version 24.1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue seems to be latest Support Library version 24.2.0. Setting the anchor for `FloatingButton` to a view which is not a direct child of its parent `CoordinatorLayout` is causing this.

This is a known issue as per **Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker**. You can see the issue marked as **future release for 24.2.1** at [FAB can no longer be anchored to indirect children of CoordinatorLayout](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220250).

Possible workaround from the comments in that reported issue are

- Set the anchor view of `FloatingActionButton` to direct child of `Coordinatorlayout`.

OR

- Wrap the View which you are setting as the anchor for `FloatinActionButton` inside a new `CoordinatorLayout`

> From Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker
>
> **Status: FutureRelease**
>
> **Labels: Target-Support-24.2.1**

Comment: Not very elegant but, wrapping the anchor with CoordinatorLayout and marking that CoordinatorLayout as an anchor fixed it for now.